# Dont know where to place CheckBox Code in MainActivity.java

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox, main-activity

I am working on a quiz app and ran into a basic problem, I want to implement a checkbox where if both answers are correct, the score should get updated, I don't know where to place the code in java.

Basically this is how the app should work, total questions 5, each carrying 2 marks, three MCQ in which one is correct, 4th question both answers are correct, so we add checkbox, each checkbox carries one mark,then the editText field so that user can add his own comments, after all the questions are answered by user, then and only then, after clicking on the submit button, Score should be presented to user!
Thank you

[image: Each question carries 2 marks, the problem is checkboxes are not working]

> I want to know how to simply use check box to update score

**MainActivity.java file here**

```
package com.example.android.quizatlast;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int Totalscore = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //toasts , onclick , and distroying buttons for next time


        final Button buttononeone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1_1);
        final Button buttononetwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1_2);

        buttononeone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int score = 2;
                Totalscore = Totalscore + score;
                Score(Totalscore);
                buttononeone.setEnabled(false);
                buttononetwo.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });
        buttononetwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Ahh,Wait for the score";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

                buttononetwo.setEnabled(false);
                buttononeone.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        final Button buttontwoone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2_1);
        final Button buttontwotwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2_2);

        buttontwoone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Dehli,City you should must visit";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                buttontwoone.setEnabled(false);
                buttontwotwo.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

        buttontwotwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int score = 2;

                Totalscore = Totalscore + score;
                Score(Totalscore);

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Ahh,mumbai is  a beautiful place";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                buttontwotwo.setEnabled(false);
                buttontwoone.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

        final Button buttonthreeone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3_1);
        final Button buttonthreetwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3_2);
        buttonthreeone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int score = 2;

                Totalscore = Totalscore + score;
                Score(Totalscore);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Agra , wonders are waiting there for you";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                buttonthreeone.setEnabled(false);
                buttonthreetwo.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

                //PROBLEM HERE

        CheckBox checkBoxfourone = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Checkbox4_1);
        boolean check4_1 = checkBoxfourone.isChecked();
        CheckBox checkBoxfourtwo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Checkbox4_2);
        boolean check4_2 = checkBoxfourtwo.isChecked();
        Score(Totalscore);
    }

    private int checkscore(boolean check4_1,boolean check4_2) {
        int score = Totalscore;
        if (check4_1) {
            Totalscore = Totalscore + 1;
        }
        if (check4_2) {
            Totalscore = Totalscore + 1;
        }
        return Totalscore;
    }

                //TILL HERE
    public void Score(int score) {

        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }public void reset(View view){
        Score(Totalscore = 0);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topping"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Name_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Email_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Toppings"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Whipped Cream"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chocolate_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Chocolate"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_below="@id/topping"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="quantity!"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >   <Button
            android:onClick="decrement"        android:id="@+id/decrement"
            android:layout_below="@id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/increment"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
            <Button
                android:onClick="increment"
                android:id="@+id/increment"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_view"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linear"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="order summary"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/order_summary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/order_summary_text_view"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"
            android:text="order" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: do you want to check whether checkboxes are selected only when submit button is clicked?

Comment: Yes , but is there anyway to simplify the stuff , i am at very basic level , can we define check box variable , then use findviewbyid in oncreate to connect the check box to the code and then create a simple on click method in which we update the score? App is working fine till question 3 , about the submit button ,currently the score is been updated real-time below the submit button , it's fine for now , i just need help for checkboxes and edit text to get input from user

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the score only after submit button is clicked, then just move your `isChecked()` code into your `submitOrder` method so that only after the user clicks the submit button we will check whether checkboxes are selected or not.

If you want to update the score in realtime follow Rahul Chaudhary's answer and once both checkboxes are checked disable both.

Answer (score 0):

When you are press submit button tack all checked value from checkbox and 
use validation

```
checkValidation(){
    if(checkbox1.equal(correct anwser1) && checkbox2.equal(correct anwser2) 
    ) 
           {
       return true
         }else{
     return false
        }}
```

and check in on submit

```
   submit.setOnclick(new.....
       onclick(){
       if( checkValidation()){
      Toast(answer is right)
       }else{
    Toast(answer is wrong)
   }
    }
```

)